# Is there a way to use the Facebook Unity SDK with the Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to use a Page access token in the Facebook Unity SDK with Graph API to post as a page. But there is no variable to send the token with, so I don't get the SDK to use the right token. In the Javascript SDK there is one.

So I am asking desperately: Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Im trying to find a solution with a different approach via Javascript. It's the same **problem**, but how is that the same **question**?

Comment: OK. But I don’t think there is any way to use the Unity SDK “with” the JS SDK. If you can embed the JS SDK in parallel somehow, then you will still have to get the page token from unity to JS ... and then you might as well do the whole thing in JS to begin with. Btw., I hope you only want to be able to post to a page the current app user is an admin of? Because if you want just any user to post as your page, then you need to do it server-side - because your page token should never be exposed in client-side code.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So what i was thinking is: I can get the pages access token as string via the Unity SDK but I can't use it because – either I don't know how, or there is just now way inside the Unity SDK. But getting the string from C# to Javascript inside Unity wont be the problem. If there is a way to use the Javascript SDK inside Unity I could use the `params` from `FB.api(path, method, params, callback)` to pass on this page access token. A function the Unity SDK does not provide for some reason.

Comment: @CBroe To answer your question regarding the admin-situation: The app user will always post to a page he is admin of.